# passing Seq[Setting[_]] as one of the Project.settings() args

Tags: scala, sbt

I initialize common settings in a multi-project build.sbt as follows:

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq( version := "0.1", ..)
..
lazy val libs = Seq( "org.some" % "somelib" % "1.2.3", ..)
..
lazy val myProject = Project(..).
  settings(commonSettings, version := "0.2", libraryDependencies ++= libs)
```

Given the definition of

```
sbt.Project.settings(ss: Setting[_]*)
```

I'm confused this actually works since I'm mixing `Setting[_]` and `Seq[Setting[_]]` args here. What am I missing, where does the flattening happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of sbt `0.13.8` the definition was changed to:

```
def settings(ss: SettingsDefinition*): Project =
  copy(settings = (settings: Seq[Setting[_]]) ++ ss.flatMap(_.settings))
```

which is where the flattening happens, and `SettingsDefinition` is defined as:

```
sealed trait SettingsDefinition {
  def settings: Seq[Setting[_]]
}

sealed class Setting[T] private[Init] (
  val key: ScopedKey[T], val init: Initialize[T], val pos: SourcePosition
) extends SettingsDefinition {
  def settings = this :: Nil
  ...
}

final class SettingList(val settings: Seq[Setting[_]]) extends SettingsDefinition

object SettingsDefinition {
  ...
  implicit def wrapSettingsDefinition(ss: Seq[Setting[_]]): SettingsDefinition =
    new SettingList(ss)
}
```

Note:

- every individual setting is a `SettingsDefinition`
- any `Seq[Setting[_]]` is auto-lifted into a `SettingsDefinition`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.Sure enough, I was running sbt 0.13.8 and looking at 0.13.7 documentation.

Comment: Hey @PeterMehlitz I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. That way it's marked as an answered question for future SO users (for instance in this case if people are looking for answered and accepted sbt questions). Thanks!